# ExpressJS req.body always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem with ExpressJS, I can not read POST data.

I have tried several solutions and looked meticulously at my code and can not find the error.

When I visit /login/ and insert an E-Mail and Password and post it to my server, "req.body" is always empty.

[image]

When I post the data with Postman with the Content-Type set to x-www-form-urlencoded, then I can read the data, but if I post them with my browser (tried Firefox, Edge), req.body is always empty.

I also tried to set the header, but it also does not work.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ip = require('ip');

var dburl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/jsShop";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/css', express.static('public/css'));
app.use('/images', express.static('public/images'));

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', [
    'views',
    'public/products'
]);


app.get('', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index');

});

app.get('/index', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index');

});

app.get('/technik', function(req, res) {

    res.render('technik');

});

app.get('/kontakt', function(req, res) {

    res.render('kontakt');

});

app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {

    res.render('admin');

});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

    res.render('login');

});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {

    res.render('register');

});

app.get('/products/articleoftheday', function(req, res) {

    res.render('articleoftheday');

});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    
    res.redirect('/login');
});


app.post('/register', function(req, res) {

    

});

app.post('/kontakt', function(req, res) {

    
    
});

/*
function testDB() {

    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, db) {

        if (err) throw err;

        var dbobject = db.db("jsShop");

        dbobject.collection("users").insertOne(data, function(err, res) {

            if (err) throw err;
            console.log();

        });
    });
}
*/

app.listen(80, function(err) {

    console.log('Server running on ' + ip.address() + ":80");

});
```

This is the HTML code for the login page

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <br>
    <label for="email" id="emaillabel">E-Mail:</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="emailinput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="passwort" id="passwortlabel">Passwort:</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="passwortinput">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log-In" id="loginsubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: What does the `form` element in the login page HTML look like?

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: Unrelated, but the label "for" property should refer to the id of an input.

Comment: I solved the problem! I forgot to add "name" in the input tag of HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form fields don't have `name` attributes, so they aren't included in the form submission. Only non-`disabled` elements with a `name` are submitted. (For `input type="checkbox"` and `input type="radio"`, they also have to be be checked to be submitted.)

So for instance, your email input might be:

```
<label for="emailinput" id="emaillabel">E-Mail:</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="emailinput" name="email">
```

Two changes there:

1. I Added `name="email"` to the `input`. That's the name that will be submitted with the form.
2. I changed the `for` on `label` to match the `id` on `input` (that's how you link the label to the input). (This isn't necessary for the submission, but it is necessary to correctly link the label to the `input` since you're not putting the `input` *inside* the `label`.)

Comment: Yes i noticed it right now, thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I had to add the "name" property to the form input tags:

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.